# Add iterating number to tag name

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml part:

```
<tag>
    <tagIn>test</tagIn>
    <tagIn>test</tagIn>
    <tagIn>test</tagIn>
</tag>
```

I need to get by xslt transformation:

```
  <tag>
    <tagIn1>test</tagIn1>
    <tagIn2>test</tagIn2>
    <tagIn3>test</tagIn3>
</tag>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a "Identity transform" with a special rule for "tagIn".
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tagIn">
        <xsl:element name="{concat('tagIn', count(preceding-sibling::tagIn)+1)}" >
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<tag>
        <tagIn1>test</tagIn1>
        <tagIn2>test</tagIn2>
        <tagIn3>test</tagIn3>
</tag>
```